# Gst-launch script suddenly not working

Tags: gstreamer

I have a script for recording output sound [Youtube/Skype] based on gst-launch using a 'pulsesrc device=$monitor' line where the $monitor is parsed via 'pactl stat' and this script worked fine in versions UP to the latest [11.10]. There are no error messages, it seems to record, but the resulting mp3 is blank. Recording from mic is fine and all . I have all latest updates applied.

Comment: I think I have discovered why this didn't work, I upgraded to Oneiric, this wasn't a clean install. I removed all files in $HOME/.pulse and rebooted and the problem was gone, all working now

Answer (score 3):

*as per a comment to the question*

> I think I have discovered why this didn't work, I upgraded to Oneiric, this wasn't a clean install. I removed all files in `$HOME/.pulse` and rebooted and the problem was gone, all working now.